# How to get a "notify after move" event with MFC sliders?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, slider

When editing a MFC slider control, I can tick on "notify before move" and then associate a method to the TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING event to define what to do when a user moves the slider.

But, as I want to update a label value depending on the current slider position, I actually need a "notify after move" event. Is there a w ay to get this event?

Answer (score 1):

Add method for [NM_RELEASEDCAPTURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification. E.g.

`ON_NOTIFY(NM_RELEASEDCAPTURE, IDC_SLIDER1, &CSliderTestDlg::OnNMReleasedcaptureSlider1)`